# Calculate CosmosDB size of query in SQL API, character encoding

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

As per documentation , the upper limit on query size is 256kb , but how do i calculate this size ?

Does the sql api treat 1 character as 1 byte ? What is the encoding standard in Cosmos ?

Edit 1 : I am not using a stored procedure/trigger/function. I am passing the query parameters through a java(spring boot) application using the query methods.
UTF-8 is the default encoding standard for java 8.

Edit 2 : So i'm basically trying to figure out what will be the size of the sql query that results from the ReactiveCosmosRepository's findBySomethingIn(List list) method - that transaltes to the "where -- IN" clause in SQL.
I am asking this because i got an **exception** saying something like **query exceeded the limit of 262144 bytes.**

Comment: How about string.length on the query string?

Comment: I am not writing a stored procedure/trigger/function. Where do i perform the "string.length" ? Also, i read in the documentation - "Maximum size of an item 2 MB (UTF-8 length of JSON representation)" . Does this mean 1 JSON character occupies 1 byte as per the UTF-8 standard ?

Comment: Also, if i have a query like select * from c where c.id in ("A","B","C","D") then will the comma and double quotes also count ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the query text in a string parameter then get the length of it.

```
string x = "Select * from c where c.property = 'foo'";
Console.WriteLine($"Length of x = {x.Length}");
```

In Java.

```
String x = "Select * from c where c.property = 'foo'";
System.out.println("Length of x = " + x.length());
```

Comment: Any suggestion for a non-C# coder like me ? I am using this with my Java application(strange but true).

Comment: added java equivalent.

Comment: ok, so you're saying that the length of the query in Java/C# will be the same for Cosmos Database ? Im assuming that's because CosmosDB also uses the UTF-8 encoding standard ?

Comment: and i am not executing the query as "select * ... " .  I am using the query methods of ReactiveCosmosRepository in my Java(Spring) application.